# Removing the first specified type found from a nested pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

For example,

```
using NestedPack = Pack<long, char, double, Pack<long, int, short, int>, char, int>;
```

Then

```
RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPack<int, NestedPack>::type
```

is supposed to give

```
Pack<long, char, double, Pack<long, short, int>, char, int>
```

First, I took care of the case of a non-nested pack:

```
template <typename T> struct Identity { using type = T; };

template <typename, typename, typename...> struct RemoveFirstFoundFromPackHelper;

template <typename RemoveMe, template<typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct RemoveFirstFoundFromPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<>, Types...> {
    using type = P<Types...>;
};

template <typename RemoveMe, template<typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Types>
struct RemoveFirstFoundFromPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<First, Rest...>, Types...> : 
    std::conditional<std::is_same<RemoveMe, First>::value,
        Identity <P<Types..., Rest...>>,
        RemoveFirstFoundFromPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<Rest...>, Types..., First>
    >::type {};

template <typename, typename> struct RemoveFirstFoundFromPack;

template <typename RemoveMe, template<typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct RemoveFirstFoundFromPack<RemoveMe, P<Types...>> : RemoveFirstFoundFromPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<Types...>> {};
```

This was tested to work correctly (using `std::is_same`).  But I'm stuck with the nested case.  This was my latest attempt, which gives incorrect results (though I couldn't trace why):

```
template <typename>
struct IsPack : std::false_type {};

template <template<typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct IsPack<P<Types...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename...> struct MergePacks;

template <typename Pack>
struct MergePacks<Pack> : Identity<Pack> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types1, typename... Types2, typename... Packs>
struct MergePacks<P<Types1...>, P<Types2...>, Packs...> : MergePacks<P<Types1..., Types2...>, Packs...> {};

template <typename, typename, typename> struct RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPackHelper;

template <typename RemoveMe, template<typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<>, P<Types...>> {
    using type = P<Types...>;
};

template <typename RemoveMe, template<typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Types>
struct RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<First, Rest...>, P<Types...>> :
    std::conditional<std::is_same<RemoveMe, First>::value,
        Identity <P<Types..., Rest...>>,
        typename std::conditional<IsPack<First>::value,
            RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<Rest...>, typename MergePacks<P<Types...>,
                typename RemoveFirstFoundFromPack<RemoveMe, First>::type>::type>,
            RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<Rest...>, P<Types..., First>>
        >::type
    >::type {};

template <typename, typename> struct RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPack;

template <typename RemoveMe, template<typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPack<RemoveMe, P<Types...>> :
    RemoveFirstFoundFromNestedPackHelper<RemoveMe, P<Types...>, P<>> {};
```

I know there must be a better way than this.

Of course, once this problem is solved, then removing *all* instances of the specified type found from the nested pack should be just a simple variation of the solution (I've already done that for the non-nested case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IsPack` trait would match pretty much every template under the sun as long as it doesn't have a non-type parameter, which is a rather bad idea.

```
template <class...> struct Pack {};

template <class, class, class = Pack<>> struct Remove_First;

// First one isn't a pack, and isn't what we are looking for.
template <class R, class F, class...Args1, class...Args2>
struct Remove_First<R, Pack<F, Args1...>, Pack<Args2...>> : Remove_First<R, Pack<Args1...>, Pack<Args2..., F>> {};

// First one is the type we are looking for.
template <class R, class...Args1, class...Args2>
struct Remove_First<R, Pack<R, Args1...>, Pack<Args2...>>  { using type = Pack<Args2..., Args1...>; };

// Didn't find the type
template <class R, class...Args>
struct Remove_First<R, Pack<>, Pack<Args...>>  { using type = Pack<Args...>; };

// Nested pack: Attempt to remove R from the nested pack
// Use is_same to check if a removal occurred and proceed accordingly
template <class R, class...Args1, class...Args2, class...ArgsNested>
struct Remove_First<R, Pack<Pack<ArgsNested...>, Args1...>, Pack<Args2...>> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<
                 std::is_same<typename Remove_First<R, Pack<ArgsNested...>>::type, Pack<ArgsNested...>>::value,
                 typename Remove_First<R, Pack<Args1...>, Pack<Args2..., Pack<ArgsNested...>>>::type,
                 Pack<Args2..., typename Remove_First<R, Pack<ArgsNested...>>::type, Args1...>>::type;
};

// if the type to remove is a Pack, and the first type in the list is a Pack,
// and they are the same pack, then remove it and we are done.
// if they are not the same Pack, then this specialization won't match,
// and we go into the recursion case as normal.
template <class...Args1, class...Args2, class...ArgsNested>
struct Remove_First<Pack<ArgsNested...>, Pack<Pack<ArgsNested...>, Args1...>, Pack<Args2...>> {
    using type = Pack<Args2..., Args1...>;
};

template<class R, class Pack>
using remove_first_t = typename Remove_First<R, Pack>::type;
```

The first three partial specializations handle removal from a non-nested pack. A nested pack is handled by the fourth partial specialization. It recursively performs the removal on the nested pack. If a type is removed (and so the resulting type is not the same as the original nested pack type), then we are done. Otherwise, we simply continue to process the rest of the outer pack as usual. The final specialization handles the case where the type to be removed is a `Pack` itself, as otherwise when the type is present both the second and the fourth partial specialization will match, and neither is more specialized than the other, resulting in an ambiguity error.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efce6edc19ebdcee).

Comment: This is very beautiful!  I upvoted for it, of course.  Very high order thinking there.  But one thing:  `remove_first_t<Pack<int, long>, NestedPack>` results in ambiguity error.

Comment: @prestokeys Fixed with an extra partial specialization.